# Share Contact List in Outlook 2010 using LDAP

Tags: ldap, outlook-2010

Our company would like to share our contact list in Outlook 2010. However, as we do not have Exchange, we cannot use the share contact feature in Outlook 2010.

We would like to use LDAP to share our contact list as stated in this website:
https://kb.wisc.edu/wiscmail/page.php?id=13789

As far as I know, if I add a new contact in Outlook, LDAP would not sync with it and thus I need to edit it on web. But, may I know if Outlook could get the latest contact list on LDAP server after I amend the list?

Or is there any other good suggestion for share contact list in Outlook 2010?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes, Outlook can retrieve an up-to-date user list from your Active Directory server, but it will not happen immediately after you add\delete a user, and it's only a one way sync from Active Directory -> Outlook. An update is triggered every 24 hours (by default), in which the contact list would be synced with the users existing under the Search Base you specified in Step #10 (of the link you provided).

That being said, for contacts you wish to share, you should just be adding them as users to Active Directory, instead of adding them directly to your contact list in Outlook. You'll experience the noted latency in seeing newly added users (same goes for users that you delete as well), but it's nice only having to add them in one place, and they can then be shared amongst all of your users.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your contacts in Microsoft Outlook or Outlook Express with the addind, from your LDAP server with

https://github.com/fquiroz01/LDAPSyncOutlook/

Install the App in the computer with Microsoft Outlook or Windows Mail the App keep contacts sync with the LDAP server and mail client contacts.